# Why does a plan with FULL optimization show simple parameterization?

Tags: sql-server, execution-plan, trivial-plan, simple-parameterization

I read that only [Trivial Plans can be Simple Parameterized](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/psssql/2013/12/04/how-simple-parameterization-works/), and that not all queries (even when the plan is Trivial) [can be Simple Parameterized](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/sqlprogrammability/2007/01/11/4-0-query-parameterization/).

Then why is [this plan](https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/?id=HkOMIb-CM) showing Full Optimization, and Simple Parameterization at the same time?

[image: NUTS]

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Simple Parameterization is attempted when a *trivial* plan is found. The parameterization attempt may be considered *safe* or *unsafe*.

The key point is that a trivial plan is *found* and considered *safe*. If the cost of the trivial plan exceeds the `cost threshold for parallelism`, the optimizer will go on to later stages of optimization, where parallel plans may be considered. Whether the final result is a serial or parallel plan, it will be simple parameterized if the safe trivial plan found (*but not ultimately used*) was parameterized.

In the question example, setting the `cost threshold for parallelism` higher than the cost of the trivial plan will allow the optimizer to stop at that stage.

---

Looking at the query plan isn't always enough to figure out if your query has actually been Simple Parameterized.

The safest way is to check some DMVs to verify:

```
/*Unsafe auto param*/
SELECT *
FROM sys.dm_os_performance_counters AS dopc
WHERE dopc.counter_name LIKE '%Unsafe Auto-Params/sec%';

/*Safe auto param*/
SELECT *
FROM sys.dm_os_performance_counters AS dopc
WHERE dopc.counter_name LIKE '%Safe Auto-Params/sec%';

/*Trivial Plans*/
SELECT * 
FROM sys.dm_exec_query_optimizer_info AS deqoi 
WHERE deqoi.counter = 'trivial plan';
```

---

Additionally, you can also use undocumented trace flag 8607, but not as an `OPTION` clause hint. Using the `OPTION` clause prevents a trivial plan.

```
DBCC TRACEON(8607, 3604);
/*Wait*/    

/*Run*/     
SELECT u.CreationDate, u.Id
FROM dbo.Users AS u
WHERE u.Reputation = 2;

/*Clean up*/
DBCC TRACEOFF(8607, 3604);
```

If the plan is considered safe for Simple Parameterization, you'll see a message confirming it here.

> ```
> ********************
>
> ** Query marked as Cachable
>
> ** Query marked as Safe for Auto-Param
> ```

Comment: Just making sure: is "Query marked as Cachable" in the output sufficient to indicate simple parameterisation or should I also see the second line? I have a scenario as in original question, but the query seems not simple parameterised (from looking at plan cache), but (again) in the plan there is a warning for Unmatched Indexes as if the query was parameterised indeed. Confusing.