# SQL Server estimating badly

Tags: sql-server, performance, query, execution-plan

I have a heap with over a million inserts daily. This table is a "staging table" where messages are received and sent to differens queues that are processed by the application.

A stored proc named `dbo.leg_msgs` does an `UPDATE` (show plan https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/?id=ryw9SDGoD) on this table, using an covered index with columns starting from most selective to least selective.

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[leg](
    [guid_operacao] [uniqueidentifier] NOT NULL,
    [dt_hr_entrada] [datetime] NOT NULL,
    [dt_hr_envio] [datetime] NULL,
    [id_fila] [int] NULL,
    [str_protocolo] [text] NOT NULL,
    [flg_enviar] [char](1) NOT NULL,
    [nr_ctrl_if] [char](20) NULL,
    [id_legado] [int] NULL,
    [tp_mensagem] [int] NOT NULL,
    [flag_sentido] [char](1) NULL,
    [flg_proc_util] [char](1) NOT NULL,
    [guid_protocolo] [uniqueidentifier] NOT NULL,
    [str_protocolo_enviada] [text] NULL,
    [fl_montou_protocolo] [char](1) NULL,
    [dt_hr_lock] [datetime] NOT NULL,
    [guid_lock] [uniqueidentifier] NOT NULL,
    [dt_hr_ok_leg] [datetime] NULL,
    [flg_ret_legado] [bit] NOT NULL,
    [flg_enviada] [bit] NOT NULL,
    [dt_hr_legado] [datetime] NULL
) ON [PRIMARY] TEXTIMAGE_ON [PRIMARY]
GO
```

Stored proc:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[leg_msgs] (  
@pTipoMensagem     INT     = NULL,   
@pIntegracaoViaSQL CHAR(1) = 'N',  
@pIdFila           INT     = NULL  
)  
AS  
BEGIN  
      
    SET NOCOUNT ON  
      
    DECLARE @guid_operacao   char(36),  
    @guid_protocolo   char(36),  
    @dt_hr_entrada   datetime,  
    @dt_ini    datetime,  
    @dt_fim    datetime,  
    @ds_strong_id   varchar(max),  
    @str_protocolo   varchar(max),  
    @cd_msg    varchar(10),  
    @nm_fila   varchar(100),  
    @id_tag_numctrl   varchar(20),  
    @id_status_matera  varchar(5),  
    @evento_id   varchar(10),  
    @dt_hr_entrada_str  varchar(50),  
    @nm_tag_sit_lanc  varchar(200),  
    @nm_proc_montagem_protocolo varchar(100),  
    @strSQL    nvarchar(1000),  
    @dt_movto   varchar(10),  
    @tempo_espera   numeric(20, 10),  
    @dt_hr_lock   datetime,  
    @guid_lock   char(36),  
    @montou_prot   char(1),  
    @id_fila_rep   int,  
    @qtd_regs   int,  
    @bol_delete   bit  
       
    -- Valores para @tempo_espera  
    --    0.00069445 (00:02:00)  
    --    0.00104167 (00:01:30)  
    --    0.00069445 (00:01:00)  
    --    0.00034724 (00:00:30)  
    SET @tempo_espera = 0.00069445  
      
    SET @dt_movto   = CONVERT(varchar(10), getdate(), 112)  
    SET @dt_hr_lock = getdate()  
    SET @guid_lock  = newid()  
    SET @dt_ini     = CAST(@dt_movto + ' 00:00' AS datetime)  
    SET @dt_fim     = CAST(@dt_movto + ' 23:59' AS datetime)  
    
      
    SELECT @qtd_regs = 1  
    FROM dba.dbo.leg WITH (NOLOCK)   
    WHERE tp_mensagem    = @pTipoMensagem  
    AND dt_hr_entrada BETWEEN @dt_ini AND @dt_fim  
    AND flg_enviar     = 'S'  
    AND flg_proc_util  = 'N'  
    AND id_fila       = @pIdFila  
    AND dt_hr_lock    <= CONVERT(varchar(23), getdate() - @tempo_espera, 121)  
    OPTION (RECOMPILE)  
      
    IF @@ROWCOUNT <> 0 BEGIN  
    BEGIN TRANSACTION  
        UPDATE dba.dbo.leg WITH (ROWLOCK READPAST)  
            SET dt_hr_lock = '19000101',  
            guid_lock  = '00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000'  
            WHERE tp_mensagem    = @pTipoMensagem  
            AND dt_hr_entrada BETWEEN @dt_ini AND @dt_fim  
            AND flg_enviar     = 'S'  
            AND flg_proc_util  = 'N'  
            AND id_fila       = @pIdFila  
            AND dt_hr_lock    <= CONVERT(varchar(23), getdate() - @tempo_espera, 121)  
      
        IF @@ERROR = 0 BEGIN  
            COMMIT TRANSACTION  
        END  
        ELSE BEGIN  
            ROLLBACK TRANSACTION  
            RETURN  
        END   
    END  
            
    SET NOCOUNT OFF  
      
END
```

Normally it runs quickly (about 30-50ms), but if the number of rows returned gets above 5000, it starts running above 100-200ms.

My first approach was to rebuild table and indexes, but SQL Server is still missing estimates.  The screenshot below is after the rebuild.

[image: Estimatives]

```
CPU time = 0 ms,  elapsed time = 0 ms.
Table 'leg'. Scan count 1, logical reads 16321, physical reads 0, read-ahead reads 0, lob logical reads 0, lob physical reads 0, lob read-ahead reads 0.
Table 'Worktable'. Scan count 1, logical reads 32676, physical reads 0, read-ahead reads 0, lob logical reads 0, lob physical reads 0, lob read-ahead reads 0.
```

Any thoughts?

edit:

SQL Server 2017, but my current COMPATIBILITY_LEVEL = 110

As a test, I created a clustered index, rebuild everything but still getting bad estimates.

```
alter table leg add id bigint identity(1,1)
    
create clustered index ix_id on leg (id)
    
alter index all on dbo.leg rebuild
```

```
CPU time = 0 ms, elapsed time = 5 ms.
Table 'leg'. Scan count 1, logical reads 49703, physical reads 0, read-ahead reads 30, lob logical reads 0, lob physical reads 0, lob read-ahead reads 0.
Table 'Worktable'. Scan count 1, logical reads 32724, physical reads 0, read-ahead reads 0, lob logical reads 0, lob physical reads 0, lob read-ahead reads 0.
```

New plan: https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/?id=rkZ6mtzoP

**Helpful **links related suggested by @NikitaSerbskiy

[Why does SQL Server use a better execution plan when I inline the variable?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/206815/why-does-sql-server-use-a-better-execution-plan-when-i-inline-the-variable/206817#206817)
[Why You’re Tuning Stored Procedures Wrong (the Problem with Local Variables)](https://www.brentozar.com/archive/2014/06/tuning-stored-procedures-local-variables-problems/)

Comment: Per your last update, I do see that didn't make much difference, but I'm also curious if you dropped your nonclustered index and directly created your clustered index as a covering index on those fields in your WHERE predicates instead (theoretically this should be more direct and performant).

Comment: please see this answer of Erik Darling: https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/206815/why-does-sql-server-use-a-better-execution-plan-when-i-inline-the-variable/206817#206817

Comment: @J.D. maybe I don't undertand your sugestion...the idea is to replace my nonclustered index for a clustered index? or just add a clustered index to "convert" a table into a B-tree? I did de 2nd option.

Comment: @NikitaSerbskiy awesome tips... Replacing my local variables for literals made the estimates much better. I will test more scenarios.

Comment: @EltonKerber actually what you need to do now is to parameterize  your queries

Comment: @NikitaSerbskiy i created a nested procedure to call that statment using parameters and   the CE keeps the estimated 2093, actual 16181...I'm think good enough for the case...Thank you for your help!

Comment: @EltonKerber Sorry for the confusion, I meant trying the first thing you said (replace your nonclustered index with your clustered index). But it seems per Nikita's suggestions you were experiencing a parameter sniffing issue that I overlooked. You can try my suggestion to see if it helps any further too but if you're already good than that's cool.

Comment: The update modifies 4 indexes. What happens, if you disable them, except the one used in update?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Normally it runs quick, but if the number os rows return get greater
> than 5000, it starts being sluggish.

Didn't you face with lock escalation because of

> A single Transact-SQL statement acquires at least 5,000 locks on a
> single nonpartitioned table or index.

?
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/sql-server-transaction-locking-and-row-versioning-guide?view=sql-server-ver15

Comment: I don't think so. Because i'm simulating in a separate environment without concurrency. 
I don't see how it justify this wrong estimative

Comment: @EltonKerber, yes, it's not related to estimates. I just thought the procedure may be sluggish because of concurrency. Regarding the estimates: they are not so worst, deviation is less than 10x and it is probably caused by using of local variables.

Comment: About the lock scalation, I got your idea, make a lot of sense during the OLTP.
About the deviation, the engine is estimating 61 rows to be returned and de actual are 16 181. Even if I use adhoc statement or use recompile hint doesn't change so much.

Comment: @EltonKerber have you tried to substitute variables with exact values when execute adhoc statement?

Comment: replacing all of them for literals makes engine estimates better: estimated 2093, actual 16181.

Answer (score 1):

While it does appear that there's a little bit of a cardinality estimate issue, my guess is that isn't too farfetched for a heap table.

Moreso, in your Execution Plan (on PasteThePlan.com) shows the majority of your bottleneck is during the `UPDATE` to the Leg table. I think likely this is because it is a heap table. I also see you're selecting from the Leg table as well in your query before the `UPDATE`.

Both of these operations might be more performant if you did use a `clustered index` on your Leg table instead of it being a heap. I can't say for sure though without testing it, but I'd recommend trying it. (If you're rebuilding your Table and it's Indexes anyway, then it's virtually not much different than creating the `clustered index` on the table before the `SELECT` and `UPDATE` and dropping it after.)

Answer (score 1):

Your query updates a column (`dt_hr_lock`), but also references that column in the `where` clause. This introduces Halloween Protection, where SQL Server adds an Eager Spool or sometimes a Sort to the execution to prevent reading the updated column. Effectively the query won't execute any further until the Eager Spool completes, which will hurt performance.

In a specific case we were able to eliminate the Halloween Protection, which sped up the query considerably on our larger tables ( >1M )

In this case I would try to eliminate the need to access the column `dt_hr_lock` in the `where` clause when possible. Instead of just a select to see if there are rows that need an update, create a temporary table of the rows needing update, then join that into the update, so you don't need to reference the column you update twice.