# Average Density & cardinality estimation

Tags: sql-server, cardinality-estimates, troubleshooting, variable

In a large web application we had a query that was running slow in code, that seemed to be working blazing fast in `SSMS`. After checking the basics like the same `SET` options, we found that there was one difference: `SSMS` used `declare @variable1` and the code used an inline parameter.

I never though that would make a difference, but the [microsoft docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/sql/performance/troubleshoot-application-slow-ssms-fast) gave the solution and even a short explanations.

> The following queries are different. The first query uses Average
> Density from the histogram for cardinality estimation, while the
> second query uses the histogram step for cardinality estimation:

SQL

```
declare @variable1 = 123
select * from table where c1 = @variable1
```

SQL

```
select * from table where c1 = 123
```

Great, problem solved. But I have no idea what the explanation actually means. I've read up on [cardinality estimation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/performance/cardinality-estimation-sql-server?view=sql-server-ver16) and understand that it's used to select that best query plan. But how does that change when using a variable or not?

- Is using a variable always better?
- If not, is there a better way to find out what to use other then "use one until it fails and check the other"?

This is the first time I really noticed this because it changed from <10ms to 10 seconds, but I'm wondering if other queries are affected by this, but just a lot less.

Comment: [How To Get Answers To SQL Server Performance Questions](https://www.erikdarlingdata.com/how-to-get-answers-to-sql-server-performance-questions/)

Comment: @ErikDarling The performance problem is already debugged and solved. I'm asking for more information why something small like this makes a difference and how to find out what I should use. It's not about a specific query anymore.

Comment: Sure, but using a local variable is a pretty big anti pattern (generally), and my guess is that there’s some other factors involved that lead to the situation. If your question isn’t about a specific query, it’s likely going to be closed as too broad. See [Why does SQL Server use a better execution plan when I inline the variable?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/206817/32281) as an example.

Comment: Thanks for the link. It has the exact opposite problem where the local variable is worse. But it also has some pointers on what is happening and that is what I'm looking for.

Comment: Yep -- that's exactly what I was getting at -- it's a weird situation for a local variable to produce better plans (especially across a wide variety of search arguments) so more information here might lead to a better overall solution for you.

Comment: I wouldn't say the problem is unusual. Stale stats or parameter sniffing can cause these symptoms.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why does SQL Server use a better execution plan when I inline the variable?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/206815/why-does-sql-server-use-a-better-execution-plan-when-i-inline-the-variable)

Answer (score 0):

**Is using a variable always better?**

No, it is not. Using a variable will prevent SQL from creating an optimal plan, as SQL does not know the contents while creating the plan. As you found, it will create a plan for the ‘average’ metrics.

**If not, is there a better way to find out what to use**
Knowing your data will be a good start. For example, if you know you have negative parameter sniffing issues, and know the average will be good enough, you may want to use it (temporary) until you have found a better solution for the specific problem.