# Two Databases using query store - one saves Paramerized Queries as literals in sys.query_store_sql_text , the other saves them as parameterized

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2019, query-store, simple-parameterization

I have two test databases - `AdventureWorks2012` and `StackOverflow2010` on the same SQL Server:

```
Microsoft SQL Server 2019 (RTM-CU21) (KB5025808) - 15.0.4316.3 (X64) 
    Jun  1 2023 16:32:31 
    Copyright (C) 2019 Microsoft Corporation
    Developer Edition (64-bit) on Windows 10 Enterprise 10.0 <X64> (Build 19044: )
```

I enable Query Store on both databases like so:

```
USE [master]
GO
ALTER DATABASE [AdventureWorks2012] SET QUERY_STORE = ON
ALTER DATABASE [AdventureWorks2012] SET QUERY_STORE (OPERATION_MODE = READ_WRITE)
ALTER DATABASE [StackOverflow2010] SET QUERY_STORE = ON
ALTER DATABASE [StackOverflow2010] SET QUERY_STORE (OPERATION_MODE = READ_WRITE)
```

And run a query on each that is parameterized by simple parameterization:

```
USE AdventureWorks2012
UPDATE  Person.Person
SET     FirstName = 'John'
WHERE   LastName = 'Smith'


USE StackOverflow2010
UPDATE  Users
SET     DisplayName = 'John Smith'
WHERE   Location = 'United Kingdom'
```

The query plan confirms that they have been parameterized:

[image]

If I look into the `query_store_query_text` view, I can see that Stackoverflow2010 shows the query as parameterised and Adventureworks shows the query as a literal

```
USE AdventureWorks2012
SELECT * FROM sys.query_store_query_text WHERE query_sql_text LIKE '%Firstname%'

USE StackOverflow2010
SELECT * FROM sys.query_store_query_text WHERE query_sql_text LIKE '%DisplayName%'
```

[image]

Why does one database show the query as parameterised in `sys.query_store_query_text` and the other show the literal query?

Comment: what is the output of SELECT name, is_parameterization_forced FROM sys.databases where name in ('AdventureWorks2012','StackOverflow2010')

Comment: Looks like an attempt at [simple parameterization](https://dba.stackexchange.com/q/206304/32281)

Comment: Hi @ErikDarling thanks - I can see that the StackOverflow plan has a `StatementParameterizationType` of 2 and the Adventureworks plan has 0. The trace flag in your linked answer also confirms that the StackOverflow example is marked as safe but the AdventureWorks one is not

Comment: Furthermore, `sys.query_store_query.query_parameterization_type_desc` returns NONE and SIMPLE for AW and SO queries respectively